# How to properly export chart as picture from WinForms to Excel?

Tags: excel, vb.net, charts

I need a stable approach to export System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting object as picture to Excel. First I need to say that I used to have a stable solution, which degraded stepwise with Win 10 upgrade and updates. My scenario is that I have a WinForms panel with multiple charts. When user clicks a button a process starts of looping the charts in this panel, copies them one by one as picture to clipboard and then pastes again one by one to Excel workbook. The codes presented below are very simplified.

Under Win 7 following code was working as charm:

```
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
chart.SaveImage(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(stream)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp)

xlWorkSheet.Paste(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString))
```

But after Win 10 installation the stability was reduced and Paste part started failing with the infamous exception 0x800A03EC. If there are for example 50 charts in the panel, one or two will fail in 80% of the cases. That is why I modified my code and put Try - Catch block. In fact 2 such blocks, because if first attempt fails to try again, because I don't like to have missing charts in Excel export. This modified solution works in 99.5% of the cases, which is perfect:

```
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
ch.SaveImage(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(stream)
Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp)

Try
     xlWorkSheet.Paste(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString))
Catch
     Try
          xlWorkSheet.Paste(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString))
     Catch
     End Try
End Try
```

Recently probably after Win 10 update the copying part (Clipboard.SetDataObject) started failing severely with the exception 'Requested Clipboard operation did not succeed'. That is why I extended SetDataObject parameters with retry times, timeouts, etc, which didn't bring improvement. Then I implemented again 2 blocks Try - Catch, which was also not enough, so finally I had to put a message to user on the chart location in Excel that pasting failed. Please note that while exporting process is working no one touches clipboard or Excel, so there is no interference from user side.

```
Dim stream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
ch.SaveImage(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(stream)
Try
     Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp, False, 16, 100)
Catch
     Try
          Clipboard.SetDataObject(bmp, False, 16, 100)
     Catch
          errorClip = True
     End Try
End Try

If errorClip = False Then
     Try
          xlWorkSheet.Paste(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString))
     Catch
          Try
               xlWorkSheet.Paste(xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString))
          Catch
          End Try
     End Try
Else : xlWorkSheet.Range("A" + row.ToString).Value = "Error copying chart. Paste it manually."
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest not to use clipboard for chart export to Excel due to its unpredictability of the stability as described in my question and also because clipboard must be not touched during operation. Better approach is to save chart object to hard drive and then to insert into Excel worksheet. This appears to be a stable solution and after many attempts I did not lose a single chart. A very simplified solution is shown below. The first row saves the image to hard drive and the second one inserts it into Excel.

```
ch.SaveImage(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ch" + chartSuffix.ToString + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\ch" + chartSuffix.ToString + ".png", False, True, 0, row, -1, -1)
```